# repeating a test condition iteratively in protractor test case not working

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a create page in which there is a textbox and dropdown, I want to create a item for each dropdown value. After creation of single item it redirects to edit page from there we have to go to create page and create item with second dropdown value iteratively.

I am trying to iterate over the dropdown values and trying to create item under each condition but the test exists after the intial item creation and it does not create item for second dropdown value.

```
describe('When create case form is valid', function(){
            it('Should be creating cases', function(){
                browser.get("xyz.com");
                browser.waitForAngular();
                element(by.id("create")).click();
                element.all(by.options('caseSubType.specID as caseSubType.specName for caseSubType in vm.newCaseSubTypes')).each(function(elem, index) {
                    elem.getText().then(function (text) {
                        elem.click();
                        element(by.model('vm.newCaseSummary')).sendKeys('test');
                        $('button[ng-disabled="!vm.hasClientIDForNewCase()"]').click();
                        browser.waitForAngular();
                        browser.get("xyz.com");
                        browser.waitForAngular();
                        element(by.id("create")).click();
                    })
                })
            });
        });
```

HTML for the create page is:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Summary</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtNewCaseSummary" ng-model="vm.newCaseSummary" ng-disabled="!vm.hasClientIDForNewCase()" name="caseSummary" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Type</td>
<td>
<select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="vm.newCaseSubTypeID" ng-options="caseSubType.specID as caseSubType.specName for caseSubType in vm.newCaseSubTypes" name="caseSubType">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<button id="create" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!vm.hasClientIDForNewCase()">Create New Case</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone suggest some other approach if this is not the correct approach or please provide a solution with current approach.

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more on how your webpage is working and what exactly you are trying to automate? And probably post your html too. It looks very vague when we try to understand it.

Comment: I have a form on Create page which has a textbox with model 'vm.newCaseSummary' and have a dropdown with ng-repeat ='caseSubType.specID as caseSubType.specName for caseSubType in vm.newCaseSubTypes'.. Now on Create page I want to create item's for each of the dropdown item by iterating over the dropdown values, means it should be creating a item with dropdown's option value 1,option value 2,option value 3 and so on..I dont want to hardcode the dropdown option which I want to select neither I want to select dropdown by using first(),last() functions.

Comment: Each time a item gets created on the Create page it redirects to the Edit screen from there I redirect to create page and I want to select the next dropdown value so that a item gets created for each dropdown value

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it recursively :

```
var cases = element.all(by.options('caseSubType.specID');
createCases(cases, 0);

var createCases = function(cases, i) {
    if (i = cases.length)
         return;

    browser.get("xyz.com");
    //browser.waitForAngular(); NOT needed, if it's an angular page
    element(by.id("create")).click();
    cases[i].click();
    element(by.model('vm.newCaseSummary')).sendKeys('test');
    $('button[ng-disabled="!vm.hasClientIDForNewCase()"]').click();
    createCases(cases, i + 1);
}
```